# How to get this substring on bash script?

Tags: shell-script, string, text-formatting

I'm working on bash script.

I have a var with a string in it. This is the string:

> tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50

Basically the format is `tSA_(id)_(year)(month)(day)_(hour)-(min)-(seg)`

Important information:

- The id can be a number from 0 to 999
- The year format is **yyyy**
- Month format **mm**
- Day format **dd**
- Hour format **24h**

The string I want to get is something like:

> 20161014111250

Which is **yyyymmddHHMMSS**

*English is not my native language, so if there's something you can't understand please tell me. Thank you.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50" | awk -F'_' '{print $3$4}' | tr -d -
```

echo the var in which the string is stored

Explanation:

`awk -F'_' '{print $3$4}'` change the field separator to `_` and print the 3rd and 4th column

The output is `2016101411-12-50`

`tr -d -` deletes `-` from the previous result.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @debal

Comment: Or simply: `echo "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50" | awk -F'_' '{gsub("-", "", $4); print $3$4}'`

Answer (score 12):

With `bash` parameter expansion:

```
$ var='tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50'

$ var="${var#*_}"  ## Extracts the portion after first `_` i.e. 
                      new `var` will be `15_20161014_11-12-50`

$ var="${var#*_}"  ## again gets the portion after first `_`, so in this case
                      after operation `var` will contain `20161014_11-12-50`

$ echo "${var//[-_]/}"  ## Replaces all `-` and `_` from `$var` with null
20161014111250
```

Comment: I like this answer more as you provided a pure bash solution as specified by the OP.

Comment: +1, but every one of those quotes except the very last pair is unnecessary and does nothing. Substitutions inside assignments (second and third line) are not subject to word splitting. And the first like doesn't have any whitespace in it.

Comment: @mtraceur I know, that's just the _muscle memory_ :)

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
var='tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50'
```

then

```
IFS=_ read -a arr <<< "${var//-/}"
printf '%s%s\n' "${arr[2]}" "${arr[3]}"
20161014111250
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` approach. Since `awk` can take multiple characters as field separators, this can be done in a single  step:

```
$ awk -F'[-_]' '{print $3$4$5$6}' <<<"$var"
20161014111250
```

Alternatively, in Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.+?_.+?_//; s/[-_]//g' <<<"$var"
20161014111250
```

Or

```
$ perl -F_ -ane 's/-//g for @F; print @F[2..$#F]' <<<"$var"
20161014111250
```

I'm using [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings), but if your shell doesn't support them just `echo $var | command` for each command above.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, a few `sed` versions:

```
echo "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50" \
| sed -rn 's/^tSA_[0-9]{1,3}_([0-9]{8})_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/\1\2\3\4/p'

echo "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50" \
| sed -r 's/^tSA_[0-9]{1,3}_([0-9]{8})_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/\1\2\3\4/'

echo "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50" \
| sed -r 's/([^_]*_){2}(.*)_(.*)/\2\3/;s/-//g'

echo "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50" \
| sed -r 's/(.*_){3}/\1/;s/[-_]//g'
```

One thing I find important is error checking. In case the variable does not conform exactly to the format you have given, the first version will yield an empty string, and the second version will yield the input string, unchanged. The third version is a `sed` version of @debal's `awk` answer, and the fourth is as concise as I can easily get it, both without specified behavior on incorrect input.

Answer (score 0):

Python solution, using `re.split()` with multiple tokens. Input string is provided as command line argument

```
$ python -c 'import sys,re;print("".join(re.split("[-_]",sys.argv[1])[2:]))' "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50"
20161014111250
```

Similar approach with ruby:

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.split(/[-_]/)[2..-1].join("")' <<<  "tSA_15_20161014_11-12-50"                                                   
20161014111250
```